# Javascript and Actionscript equivalent

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have found a lot of specific questions on this for isolated syntax, but I wondered if there was a **comprehensive list** of Actionscript and Javascript equivalent terminology?

Something like

Actionscript var num:Number = 0;
Javascript var num = 0;

... and so on

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are derivatives of [ECMAScript 262](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript).

[Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) is a great resource for comparing languages:

> Rosetta Code is a programming chrestomathy site. The idea is to
>   present solutions to the same task in as many different languages as
>   possible, to demonstrate how languages are similar and different, and
>   to aid a person with a grounding in one approach to a problem in
>   learning another.

For example, comparing [for loops in ActionScript](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/For#ActionScript)

```
var str:String = "";
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (var j:int = 1; j <= i; j++)
        str += "*";
    trace(str);
    str = "";
}
```

...to [for loops in JavaScript](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/For#JavaScript)

```
var i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1) {
  s = '';
  for (j = 0; j < i; j += 1)
    s += '*';
  document.write(s + '<br>');
}
```